# how to sync repos of bitbucket on github?

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket

i have some projects on git and some on bitbucket,

so my client needs as if some changes are made in repo in bitbucket then it must be reflected in github.

i want to do it in c#

**is there any api etc?**

Answer (score 4):

I just finished (mostly) a project to sync your GitHub repositories to BitBucket automatically (by deploying it to some cloud services):

https://github.com/xuhdev/backup-on-the-go#readme

It is written in Ruby (Not in C#, sorry), but you don't need to know ruby to make it work. But you may need to change your workflow a little bit (push to GitHub instead of BitBucket).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

See this project to see if it is of any help: https://bitbucket.org/sramana/bitbucket2github

It is in Python, but you can see the steps involved.

And there is no automated direct sync between the two hosts. You can use local hooks to do make sure the sync happens

Or you can take the simple route and just push to both ( or have a hook which will push to the other)

Comment: repository (re)moved :(

Answer (score 0):

There is [gitsharp](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp).